# I accidently made the Underworld aggro. Will they ever calm down?

Tags: fallout-3

In the Underworld I told Carol that I killed Gob, and the entire town went aggro on me. I left without killing anyone. Will they always attack me, or will they ever calm down? I haven't finished all the quests in that area, and it's a useful place to stop for trade and repairs.

Moira's quest is not currently marked as failed, so I think I still have a chance.

Comment: I think you might have to live with the consequences now. I mean, in real life, would you tell a mother that you've killed son and expect a good reaction?

Comment: @JamesJiao: No, but some offenses are recoverable in the game. And I certainly didn't expect the entire town to go after me...

Comment: I was just reading this on the fallout wiki. You might be out of luck: http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Carol#Interactions_with_the_player_character

Comment: @JamesJiao: That does describe what happened accurately, but it's unclear about whether it's permanent or not.

Comment: Iirc it is permanent, unless you fiddle with console commands. If you are into that kind of thing.

Comment: @Ids: I'm on a PS3, so I don't believe there's a way to do that. If it is permanent I'll suck it up, but it would be unfortunate. I think I'll wait a few days in-game and report back. I do think I have a chance since Moira's quest isn't marked failed, and I remember when I killed a named NPC in megaton (before I blew it up), I was able to run out of town and come back later, and they didn't try to kill me. The difference here is they went aggro from a dialog option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They do calm down. I waited several days in game and went back, and everyone was friendly again (fickle folk...).

Carol will duck when you go near her as if she's fleeing, but you can still talk to her and buy a room.

Comment: Just had this problem.  No clue what caused it.  Had to wait about 72 hours for it to work.  I did notice that a Glowing One spawned in the atrium and that caused Fawkes to go aggro.