# How can I stop the guards of Megaton from killing me?

Tags: fallout-3

I have recently started playing Fallout 3 and have just reached Megaton.

When I disarmed the bomb I accidently pick-pocketed someone and now everyone keeps trying to kill me.

Is there a way to pay off your bounty like in Skyrim or have I screwed up the entire game for myself?

Comment: I think you have kinda screwed yourself. The only way to reset this is by using console commands iirc.

Comment: You should have blown it up :p

Comment: Interesting, it seems that failed pickpocketing only results in karma loss and not being able to pickpocket again. Are you sure you only pickpocketed?

Comment: Um I may have slaughtered lem all when they attacked me :I

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have made mistakes like this in the game too and usually if I leave for a while and return much later everyone returns to friendly mode. If you only pick pocketed then it could be a glitch.

Answer (score 2):

Leave the town for a few days, then come back. They should calm down.

See this for reference: [I accidently made the Underworld aggro. Will they ever calm down?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/76370/i-accidently-made-the-underworld-aggro-will-they-ever-calm-down)